# Long time process that involved in large inserts batch

Tags: c#, mysql, c#-4.0, mysql-5.0

I have a process that takes a lot and I'm seeking ways to reduce it.
The process goes like this:

- A system manager writes to text box 10-20 lines(1-3 words each)
- Remove any empty and only white space lines
- The system multiply each line with 3000 different suffixes (by suffix I mean additional 1-2 words)
- Check for duplicate lines and remove them
- Check for illegal chars and in the process duplicates against the db - if found any - remove the line.
- For each line:

  - Select a line id (for parent id) - this is a query, like: select parentid from table where name='son'
  - Insert the line with the parent id

As I sees it the for each line insert takes the longest time but it is necessary for the parent id(it is one of the new lines). The Table has, among other, an id, name and parent id. The code is written in c# work with mysql.

For solution I think the only thing may be convert the code to be full mysql stored procedure, but I'm not sure how much it will helps.

Comment: can you make one HUGE insert instead of multiple inserts?

Comment: No, as I said it is necessary for the father id query that I do each iteration.

Comment: can you show your query? I don't get the "father id" part.

Comment: Edited and change the father to parent so it will be more clear.

Comment: I guess you are right, you'll need a SP to do that. take a look to this tutorial: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx

Comment: How much will I profit from a SP if I will not change the way it is now?? (I'll still make a lot of inserts)